# How this could be done in my-sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `group_id` int, `data_id` int, `value` varchar(19))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `group_id`, `data_id`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 20, 15, 'Supplier'),
    (2, 20, 1, 'Rahul'),
    (3, 20, 2, 'Sharma'),
    (4, 20, 3, '05/08/90'),
    (5, 20, 4, 'india'),
    (6, 21, 15, 'Consumer'),
    (7, 21, 1, 'Rajesh'),
    (8, 21, 2, 'Sharma'),
    (9, 21, 3, '05/08/88'),
    (10, 21, 4, 'india')
;
```

A table is created now i have to sort data in values column by either supplier or consumer the would be like :
For Consumer :

```
f-name l-name    dob     location
-----------------------------------
Rajesh Sharma 05/08/88   india
and so on ....
```

For supplier

```
f-name l-name    dob     location
-----------------------------------
Rahul Sharma 05/08/90   india
```

Comment: It has to be different columns?

Comment: no the column is generated by a plugin and the values are inserted with it, can i sort the data according to consumer and supplier ?

Comment: See if this would be good for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44e9e/13

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the record from the entity-attribute-value store that you have.  You can do this in various ways.  Here is a method using `group by`:

```
select max(case when data_id = 1 then value end) as fname,
       max(case when data_id = 2 then value end) as lname,
       max(case when data_id = 3 then value end) as dob,
       max(case when data_id = 4 then value end) as location 
from table1
group by group_id
having max(case when data_id = 15 then value end) = 'Consumer';
```

The `having` clause does the filtering, although you can also add a column specifying the type of record.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple function for it like this :

```
 CREATE FUNCTION GET_DATA(P_TYPE INT ,P_GROUP_ID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(19) DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
    DECLARE var varchar(19);
    select value into var  from Table1 WHERE group_id = P_GROUP_ID and data_id = P_TYPE;
 return var;
 END//



 -- you can use like this
 select GET_DATA(1,20) FIRST_NAME,
 GET_DATA(2,20) LAST_NAME,
 GET_DATA(3,20) DOB,
 GET_DATA(4,20) LOCATION;


 -- or you can use like this

select 
GET_DATA(15,a.group_id) Type,
GET_DATA(1,a.group_id) FirstName,
GET_DATA(2,a.group_id) LastName,
GET_DATA(3,a.group_id) Dob,
GET_DATA(4,a.group_id) Location
from 
 (select distinct group_id from Table1) as a;
```

fiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e9647/7